# Transfer touch event from tableviewcell to view without touch up

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, touch-event

I have a touch event problem

I used didHighLight delegate to handle touch event on tableview cell

when long press on the cell for 1 second, I add a view on top of the tableview

If it is possible that the view can detect the touch event without touch up?

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood mate, When you hold a touch, a new view is created on top, and you want that view to recogniser the same touch, if the touch has not been stopped? How do you handle touch events in that view?

Comment: Yap, I would like to know if there is a way to do this. The view I created use touchesMoved to handle the touch event.

Comment: You can also add touchesBegan, then you can detect the wanted touch, even if the touch is static, and the touch not stopped. Is that what you are trying to achieve? (Sorry, I'm not an native english speaker...)